# How do I create a MonoTouch Binding for a (^Something) block?

Tags: ios, binding, xamarin.ios, objective-c-blocks

Basically, I'm trying to create a binding for a property that is a block. It shows how to do this in the [MonoTouch Documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types#Binding_Blocks), but not for this specific case.

---

Here's the property Im trying to bind

```
    @property (copy) CouchDocumentPathMap documentPathMap;
```

CouchDocumentPathMap is defined as such

```
    typedef NSString* (^CouchDocumentPathMap)(NSString* documentID);
```

In the [documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types#Binding_Blocks), it shows how to proceed for a `(^)(id obj, BOOL *stop)` block, but not for a `(^Something)(id someParam)` block.

Comment: I haven't checked this, but my guess would be that the return value from the managed delegate should be Something instead of void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is not really useful to get "back" the block, you can bind this property like this:

```
delegate string CouchDocumentPathMap (string documentID);

[...] 

[Export ("setDocumentPathMap:")]
void SetDocumentPathMap (CouchDocumentPathMap handler);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `CouchDocumentPathMap` and, in your terms, the `Something` are not part of the block signature. `CouchDocumentPathMap` is the name of a type, the type defined by the `typedef`. If you were to write the type itself, it would be:

```
NSString* (^)(NSString* documentID)
```

Likewise, one could have declared the property without using a typedef:

```
@property (copy) NSString* (^documentPathMap)(NSString* documentID);
```

It's just like the type you are more familiar with.